# How can I optimize a SQL query without access to a showplan?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, query-optimization

I'm writing complex ad-hoc queries to extract data from a client's SQL Server. Some of the queries take a half-hour or more to run and I need them to execute in 5 minutes or less.  Unfortunately, I don't have permissions to view a showplan or on any of the `sys.dm_` views to help me optimize them.

I do have access to all of the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` and `sys` catalog views, so I know what indexes exist, and I can also use `STATISTICS TIME` and `IO` to help me measure the effectiveness of the changes.

Since I don't have the ability to compare showplans, how can I best use these tools to guide my intuitions to minimize the time-consuming trial and error? Or does anyone have any innovative solutions that have worked for them in the past.

EDIT: I only have db_DataReader permissions--I can't create new objects or indexes, but I can create temp tables and index them.

Comment: do you need to have access to `sys.dm_ views` to access `execution plan in SSMS`?

Comment: If it's the client's SQL Server, are you going to have permission to create indexes on it?

Comment: They are separate securables in SQL Server. I had hoped that using a sys.dm_ view would let me view either the plan cache or the plan of a currently executing query.

Comment: Surely your client can either grant you access or run your queries and get you a copy of the execution plan.

Comment: No ability to create indexes, but I can create temptables and index those. I'll update the qustion to reflect this.

Comment: When I excute set showplan_all on , I receive the message "SHOWPLAN permission denied..."

Comment: If you need to tune the queries you should ask to get the `showplan` permission granted.

Comment: Honestly, if you're not allowed to build indexes, I don't know that seeing the execution plan is going to be that big of a help.   See my answer below, and if that doesn't work, maybe THEN insist of getting execution plans.

Comment: @TabAlleman Thank you for your answer. I can create and index temp tables, so I'm using an approach similar to what you've described and it's been reasonably successful--your intuitions are good.  Unfortunately, I'm a minor player in all of this, unable to contact the client on my own to ask for the permissions and it would take at least a week to get an answer. in any case. So I'm trying my best to figure out how to use the time productively now.

Comment: @DataWriter In your scenario follow what your instinct tells you, ex:  If you look at a query having multiple left joins or similar sort of situations. Focus on query and analyse the best optimization. Adding indexes is not a solution always

Answer (score 1):

Here's the strategy I would explore.   It's based on the rule of thumb that the overwhelming majority of query optimization is achieved by using covering indexes to avoid Table Scans and Hash Match joins.

Look at each of the tables you need to include in your query, and the columns that you need to use in either the `JOIN ON` clause, or the `WHERE` clause.   If the table has an index that includes all those columns, then you can just go ahead and use that table in your query.  You can even use a query hint to force the query to use that covering index, but it shouldn't be needed.

If table doesn't have such an index, then you need to populate a temp table with the minimum amount of data you can get using an existing index.

For a super-simple example, say there's a table with ten columns and a million rows that only has an Index on `Column1`.  In your query, you need to `JOIN` to that table on `Column2` and include `Column3` (only) in your resultset.

But on top of that, maybe for your final resultset, you're only interested in data that has `Column1` values between 1-100.

I would create a temp table that only has `Column2` & `Column3`, with a Clustered Index on `Column2`, and populate it with an `INSERT..SELECT` that gets data from the original table using a `WHERE` clause filter on `Column1` to get only the rows I need.

This way you are building indexes on the smallest possible table which hopefully will get you a noticeable performance gain over using queries that scan the original tables.

Answer (score 0):

Study the internals of SQL Server and practice the art of query plan prediction.

Practice by writing queries against data you know cold (cardinality, density, distribution, etc). Make sure the queries are complex enough that it's a challenge. Then see if you can picture the plan in your head. Does that compare to the actual. When you start to figure out when SQL will pick LOOP v HASH v MERGE join types and other such operations like sorts, tops, etc ... Then you are starting to get a feel for it.

Regarding Internals documentation, there's never been a book to top this one: [https://www.amazon.com/Gurus-Guide-SQL-Server-Boxed/dp/0321287509/](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321287509). Since Ken is no longer with us :(, I'm not sure what the best current book is. The way I learned how to do this by feel is studying internals.

You can download a free version of SQL Server (many versions) so that you can look at query plans: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42299. Use that for practice.

There are many well documented sample databases for practice:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20987/HowTo-Install-the-Northwind-and-Pubs-Sample-Databa
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/samlester/2012/08/23/finding-the-correct-version-of-the-adventureworks-sql-server-sample-database/

Before the days of graphical query plans, we used time and io stats and showplan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-io-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-statistics-time-transact-sql
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-showplan-all-transact-sql

```
    SET STATISTICS IO ON
SET STATISTICS TIME ON
go
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON
go

SELECT o.*, od.*
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] o
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order Details] od
            ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    WHERE od.OrderID = 10248
go


    SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
StmtText                  StmtId      NodeId      Parent      PhysicalOp                     LogicalOp                      Argument DefinedValues EstimateRows  EstimateIO    EstimateCPU   AvgRowSize  TotalSubtreeCost OutputList Warnings Type                                                             Parallel EstimateExecutions
------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------
SET STATISTICS IO ON      1           1           0           NULL                           NULL                           1        NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL        NULL             NULL       NULL     SET STATS                                                        0        NULL
SET STATISTICS TIME ON    2           2           0           NULL                           NULL                           2        NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL        NULL             NULL       NULL     SET STATS                                                        0        NULL

(2 row(s) affected)

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
StmtText               StmtId      NodeId      Parent      PhysicalOp                     LogicalOp                      Argument DefinedValues EstimateRows  EstimateIO    EstimateCPU   AvgRowSize  TotalSubtreeCost OutputList Warnings Type                                                             Parallel EstimateExecutions
---------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ -------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------
SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON    1           1           0           NULL                           NULL                           1        NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL          NULL        NULL             NULL       NULL     SET ON/OFF                                                       0        NULL

(1 row(s) affected)

SQL Server parse and compile time: 
   CPU time = 0 ms, elapsed time = 0 ms.
StmtText                                                                                                                                              StmtId      NodeId      Parent      PhysicalOp                     LogicalOp                      Argument                                                                                                              DefinedValues                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          EstimateRows  EstimateIO    EstimateCPU   AvgRowSize  TotalSubtreeCost OutputList                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       Warnings Type                                                             Parallel EstimateExecutions
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------------------------------ ------------------------------ --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------ ------------- ------------- ------------- ----------- ---------------- ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ---------------------------------------------------------------- -------- ------------------

SELECT o.*, od.*
    FROM [dbo].[Orders] o
        INNER JOIN [dbo].[Order Details] od
            ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
    WHERE od.OrderID = 10248            1           1           0           NULL                           NULL                           1                                                                                                                     NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   3             NULL          NULL          NULL        0.00658094       NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             NULL     SELECT                                                           0        NULL
  |--Nested Loops(Inner Join)                                                                                                                         1           2           1           Nested Loops                   Inner Join                     NULL                                                                                                                  NULL                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   3             0             1.254E-05     254         0.00658094       [o].[OrderID], [o].[CustomerID], [o].[EmployeeID], [o].[OrderDate], [o].[RequiredDate], [o].[ShippedDate], [o].[ShipVia], [o].[Freight], [o].[ShipName], [o].[ShipAddress], [o].[ShipCity], [o].[ShipRegion], [o].[ShipPostalCode], [o].[ShipCountry], [od].[Ord NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                         0        1
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Northwind].[dbo].[Orders].[PK_Orders] AS [o]), SEEK:([o].[OrderID]=(10248)) ORDERED FORWARD)                  1           3           2           Clustered Index Seek           Clustered Index Seek           OBJECT:([Northwind].[dbo].[Orders].[PK_Orders] AS [o]), SEEK:([o].[OrderID]=(10248)) ORDERED FORWARD                  [o].[OrderID], [o].[CustomerID], [o].[EmployeeID], [o].[OrderDate], [o].[RequiredDate], [o].[ShippedDate], [o].[ShipVia], [o].[Freight], [o].[ShipName], [o].[ShipAddress], [o].[ShipCity], [o].[ShipRegion], [o].[ShipPostalCode], [o].[ShipCountry]  1             0.003125      0.0001581     231         0.0032831        [o].[OrderID], [o].[CustomerID], [o].[EmployeeID], [o].[OrderDate], [o].[RequiredDate], [o].[ShippedDate], [o].[ShipVia], [o].[Freight], [o].[ShipName], [o].[ShipAddress], [o].[ShipCity], [o].[ShipRegion], [o].[ShipPostalCode], [o].[ShipCountry]            NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                         0        1
       |--Clustered Index Seek(OBJECT:([Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details].[PK_Order_Details] AS [od]), SEEK:([od].[OrderID]=(10248)) ORDERED FORWARD)  1           4           2           Clustered Index Seek           Clustered Index Seek           OBJECT:([Northwind].[dbo].[Order Details].[PK_Order_Details] AS [od]), SEEK:([od].[OrderID]=(10248)) ORDERED FORWARD  [od].[OrderID], [od].[ProductID], [od].[UnitPrice], [od].[Quantity], [od].[Discount]                                                                                                                                                                   3             0.003125      0.0001603     29          0.0032853        [od].[OrderID], [od].[ProductID], [od].[UnitPrice], [od].[Quantity], [od].[Discount]                                                                                                                                                                             NULL     PLAN_ROW                                                         0        1

(4 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: The OP knows of these. The question was, "how can I best use these tools to guide my intuitions to minimize the time-consuming trial and error?" So they are probably after some kind of methodology.

Comment: Op clearly mentioned he cant use `showplan` query hint at all

Comment: You can [edit] your answer to add your points. That's where they belong when they are addressing the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The practical way is: instead of running complex queries in client production databases, extract the necessary data from them. And run the rest of your query to your own instance or testing environment.